# cUrl vs Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell, curl, artifactory

Can anybody explain to me why `cUrl` (the real cUrl) works but `Invoke-WebRequest` doesn’t? Same machine, same variables. To me it looks like they should both be doing the same thing, uploading a file to jfrog Artifactory.

```
$headers = @{
  'X-JFrog-Art-Api' = $apiKey
  "Content-Type" = "application/json"
  "Accept" = "application/json"
}

Invoke-WebRequest -InFile $file -Method Put -Uri "$ARTIFACTORY_HOST/third-party/test/readme.md" -Headers $headers -Verbose
```

This PowerShell doesn't work.

```
curl -T readme.md "${ARTIFACTORY_HOST}/third-party/test/readme.md " \
-H "X-JFrog-Art-Api: ${apiKey}" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Accept: application/json"
```

cUrl works.

PowerShell fails with

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -InFile $file -Method Put -Uri "https:// ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Comment: The backslashes are the way for him to go down and it's not on the PowerShell but on the cUrl. 

What do you see in Artifactory's logs? Do you see anything in the logs of Artifactory, or the reqeust is not reaching it at all?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler as Ariel correctly identified by reading my post the backslashes are for bash. I don't use backticks in PowerShell at all.
I found the answer myself. PowerShell negotiates TLS1.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out PowerShell defaults to the wrong TLS version and needs to be specifically told to use 1.2

`[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12`

Put that in front of the `Invoke-WebRequest` and all is fine.